# Chezmoi: How to ignore a file if its content exists in a different file?

Tags: dotfiles

I use [Rectangle](https://github.com/rxhanson/Rectangle) to manage my windows and [chezmoi](https://www.chezmoi.io/) to manage my dotfiles. Rectangle reads the configuration from `~/Library/Application\ Support/Rectangle/RectangleConfig.json` and renames the file then to `RectangleConfig<A_DATE_PATTERN>.json`. Chezmoi then would recreate the `RectangleConfig.json` again and again - also if nothing changed.

How to ignore in chezmoi the `RectangleConfig.json`, if its content does not differ from the latest `RactangleConfig<A_DATE_PATTERN>.json`?

P.S. Would be great if someone could create a tag for chezmoi